# InstallShield 2012: What is the proper way to connect to an Oracle database

Tags: installshield

I have an InstallScript MSI project where I need to connect to an Oracle database.

I have a tnsnames.ora file configured and the Oracle Client installed.  The following code is from the OnSQLLogin function:

```
SQLRTInitialize2();
...
nResult = SQLServerSelectLogin2( szConnection, szServer, szUser, szPassword, bWinLogin, szDB, TRUE, TRUE );
if (nResult = NEXT) then
    SQLRTPutConnectionInfor2(szConnection, szServer, szDB, szUser, szPassword );
    SQLRTPutConnectionAuthentication (szConnection, bWinLogin);
    nResult = SQLRTTestConnection2(szConnection, szServer, szDB, szUser, szPassword, bWinLogin);
    ...
endif;
```

The error message that is displayed after next is pressed is this:

```
Error 27502. Could not connect to Oracle '192.168.10.150'. 
[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle]
[Oracle]ORA=12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA(12504)
```

szServer = IP address
szDB is set to the SERVICE_NAME from tnsnames.ora

What else do I need to do to get IS to work with Oracle?

An example would be great.

Comment: Upon further examination of the log file it looks like I am having a TNS issue.  I have a tnsnames.ora file located in the Oracle ..\network\admin folder.  I have added a TNS_ADMIN env variable.  This link says that IS looks in the tnsnames.ora file: http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=171543&page=2&highlight=tnsnames.ora but the log says otherwise.

Comment: 1: CSQLServerBrowse::GetServerList() begins.     1: CSQLServerBrowse::GetServerList: Attempting to retrieve server names for Oracle. 
    1: CSQLServerBrowse::GetServerList: Retriving Oracle TNS service names registered on the local machine. 
    1: CSQLServerBrowse::GetServerList() ends. 
    1: CSQLServerList::PopulateListBoxOrComboBox: Populating the IS_SQLSERVER_LIST ListBox. 
MSI (c) (E8:14) [10:48:05:120]: Note: 1: 2262 2: ListBox 3: -2147287038 
    1: CSQLServerList::DoSQLServerList() ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always the simple things.  Turns out that when the file was saved it was named  tnsnames.ora.ora

Changed to tnsnames.ora and followed instructions in User Guide and all worked.